# Problem importing Quartz framework

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics

I have added the Quartz framework to my project, but when I compile I get the following errors:

```
ld: framework not found Quartz


Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

- Delete the framework.
- Clean all targets.
- Shut down and restart xcode.
- Try linking in the framework again.
- Rebuild your application.

Any help?

Comment: that did the trick! is this a funny quirk in xcode? can i prevent this from happening?

Comment: Just something I've picked up from experience, not sure exactly why it works. I've often found xcode to be a bit funny with adding frameworks, and whenever xcode is behaving weirdly for no apparent reason, I find cleaning all targets (which makes it rebuild everything again from scratch instead of using various resources again) often fixes it, and if that doesn't, restarting it sometimes does.